# React history.push reloads component. Want it to load only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When redirecting after component loads using history.push - my component is rendered again. Causing `componentDidMount()` function to run twice.

Here's a simplified snippet of one of my components.
I want the `componentDidMount()` to run only once - and it works as expected without the `history.push`. But when i add the `history.push` - it loads twice. (Same happens if i use `Redirect` from `react-router`)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { history } from "../../configureServices";
import { explore } from "../../routes";

export class WelcomeComponent extends React.Component<object, object> {
  componentDidMount() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    history.replace(explore);
  }
  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

Console:

```
componentDidMount
componentDidMount
```

Would love to find a way to have this run only once.

Edit: Thank you for the responses everyone. I'm going to post a quick code snippet and then post a Fiddle in a bit.

--- Update:

I am using React-Router. I build the history (along with some other services) in the configureServices.ts file.

```
// configureServices.ts
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

My index.ts looks like this:

```
import { history } from "./configureServices";

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Provider {...stores}> 
<AppComponent history={history} /> 
  </Provider>, 
document.getElementById("root") );
```

And my AppComponent which has all the routes looks like this:

```
import { History } from "history";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import * as Routes from "../../routes";

...
// Import Components
...

interface Props {
  history: History;
  ...
}

export class AppComponent extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.authStore && this.props.authStore.authenticate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={this.props.history}>
        // For toasts, please ignore for this example
        <ToastProvider
          placement={toastPlacement}
          autoDismissTimeout={toastDismissTimeout}
        >
            // Main App Div = Navbar + Components

          <div className="font-sans flex flex-col h-full text-phi-green-munsell bg-phi-gunmetal-rich-dark">
            <NavBarComponent />

            // This is where the routes are
            <div className="container mx-auto p-2 md:p-3 lg:p-4 justify-start">
              <Switch>
                <Route
                  exact={true}
                  path={Routes.homePage}
                  component={HomepageContainer}
                />
                <Route
                  exact={true}
                  path={Routes.logOut}
                  component={LogOutContainer}
                />
                <Route
                  exact={true}
                  path={Routes.welcome}
                  component={WelcomeContainer}
                />
                <Route
                  path={Routes.explore}
                  component={ExploreComponent}
                />
                <Route
                  path={Routes.searchResults}
                  component={SearchResultsComponent}
                />
              </Switch>
            </div>
            <Footer />
            <DevTools position={mobxDevToolsPosition} />
          </div>
        </ToastProvider>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you again for helping me with this.

Comment: Where is the `history.push()`?

Comment: Is the WelcomeComponent also included in the explore route?

Comment: @stever: `history` is created in `configureServices()` (Updated in the answer) using `export const history = createBrowserHistory();`

Comment: @varoons: WelcomeComponent is not in the explore route, currently its just a simple Pure.Component rendering text to test

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things that could cause your component to remount.

1. If the react component tree above this component changes.  This might be caused by something like having multiple `Route` components which display this component, but the path changes from one to the other.  Even though the same component is ultimately displayed, the `Route` component which was matched changed.
2. If the key for this component changed.  If you are doing something like using randomly generated keys, or using array indices for keys and reordering elements, then you will see components remount.

Comment: I think your point 1 is the case here. I'm going to post a JSFiddle for more information. Will reply if this is the case

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to update the question since I figured it out. I was calling `history.replace(explore)` in `componentDidMount()` - which (for reasons I don't understand well) - was causing the react component tree above this component to change as Matt H mentioned. I ended up using `Redirect` from `react-router-dom` and returning the redirect in render. Like:

```
render() {
    return <Redirect to={explore} />;
  }
```

So, I instead of making all calls in componentDidMount() and redirecting in that function as well. I made the api calls in componentDidMount() and used render to redirect. Happy it worked and thank you all for responding to my question.